# Passing jquery array to PHP with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

having a bit of an issue with sending a jQuery array to a PHP file. I've looked at similar questions on here, but mine has other elements to the data variable being sent. Here's the code:

```
var data = 'type='+e+'&offset=' + all_dates_offset + '&filters=' + filters;
$.ajax({
    url: "pos_jobs.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    cache: false,
    data:data,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(html){
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

For the data, 'e' and 'all_dates_offset' are standard variables, whereas 'filters' is an array. On the PHP side of things, I was hoping I could just use something like $_POST['filters'][0], but that is returning a null value.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `data: {type: e, offset: all_dates_offset, filters: filters},`

Comment: Follow what David has mentioned above and also refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) link's Example section first example to adopt better way to pass data.

Comment: and for the tip @BhavikShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pos_jobs.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: {type: e, offset: all_dates_offset, filters: filters},
    dataType:"json"
}).done(function(data) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: So simple, thanks @adeneo. I'll accept this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

use below

`$.ajax({
    url: "pos_jobs.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    cache: false,
    data:{'type':e,'offset':all_dates_offset,'filters':filters},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(html){
        //Do Something
    }
});`